# Regarding use of @(posedge clock) statement

Tags: verilog

I'm trying to collect 160-bits data from a wishbone port which is 32-bits and driven at each posedge of the clock. In order to able to do that, trying to use the "for" loop:

```
always @(posedge wb_clk_i) begin
   
    for (index = 0 ; index < 5 ;@(posedge wb_clk_i) index = index + 1) begin
        adrholder[index] = wbs_adr_i;
    end
    //some fsm process using 128-bit of 160-bit data
end
```

I'm not sure whether the `@(posedge wb_clk_i) index = index + 1` is going to work or not. Due to not completing the design, I could not apply the testbench.

Additionally, I am open to advice on other ways to collect the data.

Comment: The module takes 32-bit from wbs_adr_i port on each clock cycle. Total size of data which is going to collected is 160-bits. And I want to hold the data  in some register called "adrholder". What should i add more,idk.

Comment: are  you trying to fill the *addrholder* array with identical data?

Comment: Yes i am trying to fill the array with same order .

Comment: in this case the `always @(posedge...` plays the role. The loop will be executed at the posedge and all elements of the array will be assigned at the same posedge. Next posedge will cause new value to be pushed in all 5 elements of the array and so on. So, get rid of the `@(posedge...` statement in the loop. Also, use non-blocking assignments `<=` when assigning the array `adrholder[index] <= wbc_addr_i;`

Comment: If I delete the ```@(posedge wb_clk_i)``` to increment index, is the loop going to work for my purpose ? Actually that is what i want to learn.

Comment: @Ufukyill removing this statement will fix syntax errors which you should have gotten trying to compile it. In order to figure out if it works *for your purposes* you need to create a test bench which will check it and simulate and debug your code.

Answer (score -1):

I am assuming that you are trying to fill the array and the address of that array has to be incremented on a `posedge clk` behavior. Try this

```
always @(posedge wb_clk_i) begin
        adrholder[index] = wbs_adr_i;
    end
    //some fsm process using 128-bit of 160-bit data
end



always @(posedge wb_clk_i or negedge reset) begin //Add a reset port
     if(!reset) 
      index <= 'd0;
     else
      index <= (index=='d4) ? 'd0 : index + 1'd1;
   end
```